# Is that safe to use Mac OS X Maverics standard e-mail client?

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook-2011

I mean, MS Outlook is ugly and I don't like the usability, but I use my mac for work, and I need to use a client. Is that safe to use mac os client as working e-mail client? Does it backup something to iCloud? I want to be sure that everything I receive stays on my laptop and isn't distributed anywhere outside. At least at the same extent if I'd used Outlook.
Thank you.

UPDATE:
Thank you guys, I got enough explanations. I tried embedded mail-client, and I like it more.
I unchecked "Mail" in iCloud settings to be sure ))

Comment: There are other enail clients just use something else I'd you hate Outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail is completely separate to iCloud. Even if the mail setting within the iCloud preferences pane is enabled or not, all this does is give you an iCloud email address to use within Mail.

Regardless of this setting, your Mail is between your mail server (Gmail for example) and your Mac.

---

Other applications however use iCloud to sync their data. Contacts, Calendar and Reminders are the Outlook equievelants that sync to iCloud. These can be turned off inside the iCloud preferences pane.

Answer (score 0):

The default mail client on OS X has an iCloud integration. However you can easily disable it through settings --> iCloud --> uncheck Mail

[image]

Once you've unchecked that it should be just as "secure" as Outlook.

Comment: I'd also uncheck contacts when you're afraid of syncing your contacts to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, software developed by a publicly listed company such as Apple, is going to be secure as they have the resources for research and development, they have more oversight and accountability etc compared to some non-profit organisations developing open source freeware that have disclaimed any legal liability, warranty or fitness for purpose.